# Street Fighter IV Achievements on iPhone

Tags: ios, street-fighter-iv

When I finish SFIV on iPhone I get presented with a screen that says something along the lines of:

"You have unlocked the following achievements blah, blah, blah..."

What is the purpose of achievements in the game?
Where can I view all of my achievements?

As well as the message above it also has another message which will say you have a total of X achievements. However, this number never increases, it is always just 1 or 2. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be logged into Apple's [Game Center](http://www.apple.com/game-center/) if you want to view or track your achievements in this game.  Game Center requires iOS 4.2 or later.  It's possible that if you don't have Game Center set up on your iDevice, that achievements won't "stick" across play sessions of the game.

I believe that Game Center has a friends list/leaderboard functionality where you can compare your achievement progress against your friends.  Other than that, I don't believe they have any special significance.

There's quite a list of achievements for this game, and they're all listed on [this page](http://www.chaptercheats.com/cheat/iphone-ipod/57379/Street-Fighter-4/unlocks/20609/), if you're interested.